# Why isn't my pathtracing code working?

Tags: python, raytracing

I've been hacking together a pathtracer in pure Python, just for fun, and since my previous shading-thing wasn't too pretty ([Lambert's cosine law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_cosine_law)), I'm trying to implement recursive pathtracing.

My engine gives an abortive output:

[image]

My pathtracing function is defined recursively, like this:

```
def TracePath2(ray, scene, bounce_count):
  result = 100000.0
  hit = False

  answer = Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

  for object in scene.objects:
    test = object.intersection(ray)

    if test and test < result:
      result = test
      hit = object

  if not hit:
    return answer

  if hit.emittance:
    return hit.diffuse * hit.emittance

  if hit.diffuse:
    direction = RandomDirectionInHemisphere(hit.normal(ray.position(result)))

    n = Ray(ray.position(result), direction)
    dp = direction.dot(hit.normal(ray.position(result)))
    answer += TracePath2(n, scene, bounce_count + 1) * hit.diffuse * dp

  return answer
```

And my scene (I made a custom XML description format) is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<scene>
  <camera name="camera">
    <position x="0" y="-5" z="0" />
    <direction x="0" y="1" z="0" />

    <focalplane width="0.5" height="0.5" offset="1.0" pixeldensity="1600" />
  </camera>

  <objects>
    <sphere name="sphere1" radius="1.0">
      <material emittance="0.9" reflectance="0">
        <diffuse r="0.5" g="0.5" b="0.5" />
      </material>

      <position x="1" y="0" z="0" />
    </sphere>

    <sphere name="sphere2" radius="1.0">
      <material emittance="0.0" reflectance="0">
        <diffuse r="0.8" g="0.5" b="0.5" />
      </material>

      <position x="-1" y="0" z="0" />
    </sphere>
  </objects>
</scene>
```

I'm pretty sure that there's some fundamental flaw in my engine, but I just can't find it...

---

Here's my new-ish tracing function:

```
def Trace(ray, scene, n):
  if n > 10: # Max raydepth of 10. In my scene, the max should be around 4, since there are only a few objects to bounce off, but I agree, there should be a cap.
    return Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

  result = 1000000.0 # It's close to infinity...
  hit = False

  for object in scene.objects:
    test = object.intersection(ray)

    if test and test < result:
      result = test
      hit = object

  if not hit:
    return Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

  point = ray.position(result)

  normal = hit.normal(point)
  direction = RandomNormalInHemisphere(normal) # I won't post that code, but rest assured, it *does* work.

  if direction.dot(ray.direction) > 0.0:
    point = ray.origin + ray.direction * (result + 0.0000001) # We're going inside an object (for use when tracing glass), so move a tad bit inside to prevent floating-point errors.
  else:
    point = ray.origin + ray.direction * (result - 0.0000001) # We're bouncing off. Move away from surface a little bit for same reason.

  newray = Ray(point, direction)

  return Trace(newray, scene, n + 1) * hit.diffuse + Color(hit.emittance, hit.emittance, hit.emittance) # Haven't implemented colored lights, so it's a shade of gray for now.
```

---

I'm pretty sure that the pathtracing code works, as I manually casted some rays and got pretty legitimate results. The problem I'm having (now) is that the camera doesn't shoot rays through *all* the pixels in the image plane. I made this code to find the ray intersecting a pixel, but it's not working properly:

```
origin = scene.camera.pos                 # + 0.5 because it      # 
                                          # puts the ray in the   # This calculates the width of one "unit"
                                          # *middle* of the pixel # 
worldX = scene.camera.focalplane.width - (x + 0.5)                * (2 * scene.camera.focalplane.width / scene.camera.focalplane.canvasWidth)
worldY = scene.camera.pos.y - scene.camera.focalplane.offset # Offset of the imaging plane is know, and it's normal to the camera's direction (directly along the Y-axis in this case).
worldZ = scene.camera.focalplane.height - (y + 0.5)               * (2 * scene.camera.focalplane.height / scene.camera.focalplane.canvasHeight)

ray = Ray(origin, (scene.camera.pos + Point(worldX, worldY, worldZ)).norm())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first question is should `if test > result:` be `if test < result:`? You're looking for the closest hit, not the furthest.

Second, why do you add `direction*0.00001` to the hit point here `n = Ray(ray.position(result) + direction * 0.00001, direction)`? That would put the start of your new ray inside the spheres. I believe then when you recursively call `TracePath2`, the dot product that you multiply by would be negative, which would help explain the problem.

Edit: updated problem

This line confuses me: `answer += TracePath2(n, scene, bounce_count + 1) * hit.diffuse * dp`. First of all `answer` will just be `Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` so you could simply `return racePath2(n, scene, bounce_count + 1) * hit.diffuse * dp`. But that still bothers me because I don't understand why you're multiplying the recursive call and `hit.diffuse`. Something like this makes more sense to me `return racePath2(n, scene, bounce_count + 1) * dp + hit.diffuse`. One more thing, you never check `bounce_count`. You're never going to recurse forever in this scene anyway but if you want to render larger scenes you'll want something like this at the beginning `if bounce_count > 15: return black`.

Edit 2:

The one thing I see that I still wonder about is the if-else towards the end. First of all I'm not entirely sure what that part of the code is doing. I think you're testing whether or not the ray is on the inside of the object. In that case your test would be like this `inside = normal.dot(ray.direction) > 0.0`. I'm just testing against `normal` instead of `direction` because using the random direction in the hemisphere could give the wrong answer. Now, if you're inside the object you want to get out, but you want to stay out if you're already out? Like I said, I'm not quite sure what that part is supposed to do.

Comment: Bah, how did I miss that? I think choosing the closest intersection would be nice. I made those changes, and things are getting interesting: my sphere on the right disappeared completely and flooded the background of the scene. I'll post and update when it finishes rendering.

Comment: Okay, now *that* glitch is fixed. It turns out `False` is smaller than *any* number, which falsely triggered a miss as a hit. `if test and test < result:` fixed that. I'll post the (almost identical-looking) update momentarily.

Comment: @Blender did you try my new suggestions? I would like to know if they helped.

Comment: Whoa, sorry. I'm not being notified about edits... I've re-written a few critical parts, and I'll update my question with annotated code.

Comment: I implemented the raytracing code from a fully-working pathtracer (written in JavaScript: http://29a.ch/2010/5/17/path-tracing-a-cornell-box-in-javascript), so I'm sure *that* part works. Right now, my biggest problem is figuring out why my camera isn't shooting its rays properly. I'll post the code, as that part has been driving me *insane* for the past two days...

Comment: @Blender just a quick guess, do you take multiple samples per pixel and then average them? If you only shoot 1 ray per pixel, then some will likely come back black. Here's a render I did with 1 sample per pixel http://twitpic.com/3guqgg that has a bunch of black pixels. This is due to the randomness in the rendering equation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that looks pretty sweet (what did you use?). I *was* doing around 30 samples/pixel, but then I found that it was *always* black; I added `print` statements randomly into the code, and it seems to be that my ray-shooting code is wrong in some way. I'm trying to figure that one out...

Comment: @Blender I can't quite tell if your ray-shooting code is correct without seeing more code, but if you used it to calculate the picture at the top, then I'm 99% sure that's not your problem. Oh and my render was one of the first I produced with a ray tracer I'm writing in Haskell (https://github.com/joelburget/Cologne)

Comment: That picture was created using a completely different method. I randomly chose a photon and figured out what pixel it intersected, but that method was impractical because the convergence was really slow. Actually (I'm now thinking aloud), I'll try reversing that code, as I *know* it works.

Comment: If you want to see *all* the code, it's available via git (it's only two files, totaling around 300 lines of code with tons of useless whitespace): https://github.com/Blender3D/Induction-Raytracer.

Comment: A bit late to ask, but does your path tracer use bidirectional path tracing? I'm trying to implement it, and it would be nice to look at some code.

Comment: I haven't gotten around to it yet :( I don't know if you're aware of this website http://ompf.org/forum/ which has a ton of good ray tracing information. If you go to the sources link I'm sure there will be something useful.

Comment: I've seen a few Google results linking to it, but I'll search that forum for some info. Thanks.